# How do I delete rows from SQL Server tables using Access & ADO?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ado

I am converting an Access 2010 database from using DAO in the native database to using SQL Server 2012 accessed by ADO. Everything has gone flawlessly without too many code changes... except for one thing:

I have some very simple temp tables in which I need to delete all the rows before using.  There are no joins or constraints on the table -- just three columns, all of which are part of the primary key.

**This is the old DAO code which worked in the MDB:**

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM Print_Tickets_TEMP;")
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

**This is the new ADO code which produces an error in SQL Server:**

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "DELETE FROM Print_Tickets_TEMP;"
```

Running this ADO code produces an error:

> Could not delete from specified tables (err 80004005).

It's obviously pretty basic stuff which works in SSMS and in an Access pass-through query.  So, I thinking there must be some sort of permission, locking or property that I'm not setting.  Note that `Connection.Execute` gets used all over the app with INSERTS and UPDATES.

The only info I found when searching for answers related to issues people had deleting from joined tables. As I noted, this is a simple standalone table.  Anyway, I'm at my wits end... if anyone has any ideas on what's missing or can explain why I can't/shouldn't be doing this, that would be greatly helpful!

edit: If it helps, this code is in a VBA module being called from an Access form.

Comment: Does this also fail? ... `CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Print_Tickets_TEMP;", dbFailOnError`

Comment: Add [this function](http://pastebin.com/mDx1QGFB) to your form, then have your form call `MsgBox TableHasPrimaryKey("Print_Tickets_TEMP")`. If it displays "False" then your ODBC Linked Table in Access does not have a Primary Key defined. That is one of the most common causes of "Could not delete ..." errors.

Comment: Thank you Gord and also Hans.  Both of your responses set me off in the right direction.  Gord, you were exactly right that the Access linked table did not have a PK like the SQL table did.  I was able to recreate the linked table (with the proper Primary Key) and then everything worked as expected.  Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a specific stored procedure causing this problem, try adding these lines to the beginning of the proc.

SET NO_BROWSETABLE OFF 
SET NOCOUNT ON

If you are querying system tables, use a forward-only cursor (to be safest, avoid ADODB.Recordset altogether).

If you are using SQL Server 7.0: if you have ANSI_WARNINGS set to OFF, see KB #259775; if you are using the ROUND() function, make sure that the parameters you are sending are not null (see KB #199105)

If you are using SQL Server 2000, and are using SELECT DISTINCT on a table with a LEFT JOIN on a view, upgrade to SQL Server 2000 Service Pack 2 (see KB #308547).

If you are using MTS transactions, try to change your approach by using transactions within SQL Server.

If none of the above solves your issue, see KB #243899.

http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/80004005-errors.html